# Странный отступ внизу блока

Tags: html, css

Внезапно наткнулся на проблему. Что не делаю - ничего не помогает.

Код HTML:

```
<div class="hero_intro_vid">
<video controls="controls" poster="video/duel.jpg">
<source src="/wp-content/uploads/videos/ow_tracer_intro.mp4" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hero_intro_vid {display: inline-block;margin-top: 30px;border: 1px solid #fff;border-radius: 10px;overflow: hidden;}
.hero_intro_vid video {width:100%;border: 2px solid #f88100;box-sizing: border-box;}
```

А на картинке результат, где виден отступ от картинки до рамки внизу. Не скажете как это исправить?

[image: Странный отступ внутри блока]

Comment: Не вижу отступа до рамки. Вижу, что окно плеера упирается в рамку. Какой браузер?

Comment: Google Chrome последней версии

Comment: А что сделать-то хотите? Плеер во всё окно?

Comment: Хочу что бы рамка вплотную облегала видео, без небольшого отступа внизу... Важно что бы она была применена не к тегу видео, а именно к тегу, в котором оно находится.

Comment: Что-то непонятно... У меня она нормально облегает `div`. Приведите весь код HTML-ки, может, там что-то с другими элементами.

Comment: Оу, вы правы! Проверил в другом документе, все нормально. Я прошел по всем другим классам и родителям и нашел line-height: 22px; который применил к body. Убрав его и применив font-size: 0; проблема исчезла. Благодарствую!

Comment: Рад, что смог помочь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте стиль для `.hero_intro_vid` `line-height:0;`

Answer (score -1):

`margin-bottom: -Xpx;` решит эту проблему

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?